# how to update sqlite database table in xamarin iOS

Tags: c#, sqlite, sql-update, xamarin

How to updated sqlite db in xamarin iOS

Used the component SQLite.NET add to component.

I have inserted 10 records into db  note.db
which do have Table `Student`

```
 public class  Student{
    [Primary autoIncrement]
    public  int id {get;set;}
    public  int marks {get;set;}
    public  string grade {get;set;}
    public  string subject {get;set;}
  }
```

Records have been inserted into table.

I want to updated Marks of Student for xyz id;

```
var updateMarks = db.Query<Student>("UPDATE Student Set marks  = ? WHERE Stockid = ?",100,stdId);

for(var check in updateMarks)
Console.WriteLine ("AFter Updated {0}", check. marks);
```

Answer (score 4):

Reading the Xamarin documentation the answer seems to be in that your **NOT** suppose to be doing a Query!

- **Execute** – Use this method (and **not Query** ) when you don’t expect rows back from the SQL (such as INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE instructions).

This is on the page [Part 3 - Using SQLite](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/data/part_3_using_sqlite_orm/)

So your updateMarks line would become =>

```
var updateMarks = db.Execute<Student>("UPDATE Student Set marks  = ? WHERE Stockid = ?",100,stdId);
```

**Execute** is the Key here